# gdal2tiles has no attribute 'generate_tiles'

Tags: python, gdal

I created a new `conda` environment with python version 3.7

Then installed

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal=2.4
```

Then installed gdal2tiles

```
pip install gdal2tiles
```

and then `python test.py`

```
#test.py
import gdal2tiles
gdal2tiles.generate_tiles('xyz.tif', 'output_dir')
```

but I am getting an error

```
AttributeError: module 'gdal2tiles' has no attribute 'generate_tiles'
```

It's the same method that I copied from the documentation but doesn't seem to work. https://pypi.org/project/gdal2tiles/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be importing the [GDAL utility gdal2tiles.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html) -- probably something to do with your working directory or your path setup.
Try this to display the attributes and methods of the class:

```
import gdal2tiles
dir(gdal2tiles)
```

Does it look anything like what you expect from the pypi library ?
https://github.com/tehamalab/gdal2tiles/blob/master/gdal2tiles/gdal2tiles.py

Is there any reason you can't use the GDAL gdal2tiles.py utility without adding the extra python library on top?